# devise_token_auth: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) during RegistrationsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using `devise_token_auth` to set up authentication for an API-only Rails app. I am testing the registration creation using `httpie` at the command line with the following command:

`http POST :3000/auth 'email=username@email.com' 'password=password' 'password_confirmation=password'`

The response is the full HTML output of the error page, and the error within is `wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)`. The offending action is `DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController#create`.

Thanks in advance for any guidance. Code is here: https://github.com/jraczak/flow-api

Devise is applied to the `User` model: [here](https://github.com/jraczak/flow-api/blob/master/app/models/user.rb)

[Routes](https://github.com/jraczak/flow-api/blob/master/config/routes.rb) is here

Comment: Can you post the error trace please...

Comment: @VamsiKrishna I can, but it's a little unruly since it's an HTML dump. I've added it to a gist here: https://gist.github.com/jraczak/d8aab28bf0a670c1f6c8a49bf0dadf45

Comment: Can you post the routes and the model for which devise is applied

Comment: @VamsiKrishna I've added direct links to the relevant model and routes.

Comment: Just remove ```has_secure_password``` and password_digest from ```validates_presence_of :name, :email, :password_digest```...Devise already does that

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Thanks, this were included before I started working with this gem. I've removed them, but the same error persists. Added here to gist: https://gist.github.com/jraczak/6b2baee3cb4ea49ac03445aca23ea3a6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148519/discussion-between-vamsi-krishna-and-justinraczak).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Summarising the chat discussion with an answer...

Just remove `has_secure_password` in https://github.com/jraczak/flow-api/blob/master/app/models/user.rb and `:password_digest` from `validates_presence_of :name, :email, :password_digest`...Devise already does that

I see that you already added encrypted_password column in your schema (https://github.com/jraczak/flow-api/blob/master/db/schema.rb) ...In that case remove the password_digest column from the table...It would work

```
rails g migration RemovePwdDigest

class RemovePwdDigest < ActiveRecord::Migration 
  def change 
    remove_column :users, :password_digest 
  end 
end
```

**What might have gone wrong even after removing has_secure_password and validation:**

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/ee01bac8b0b828b3da0d79c46115ba65c433d6c8/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb#L45

If you see this line, devise tries to call it's internal password_digest method while setting a new password or wherever you use password= method. But, as you already have a db column with name similar to the method (password_digest column), it is calling that instead of devise internal method. So, you are facing an error. (I may be wrong, this alone seems to be suspicious)

Comment: For myself and for anyone else who comes across this, would you be able to share why this had an impact if the field isn't used by devise anyway? `password_digest` was left over from when I was going to take another approach to auth.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is using [Devise Invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) with Devise Token Auth and is getting this error. Check that you are not using Rails in API only mode, specificaly inherating your ApplicationController from ActionController::API instead of ActionController::Base

Answer (score 0):

In my current model I already have a password digest. What worked for me was removing the `devise: database_authenticatable` from the User model.